# browser.runtime.setUninstallURL works on Firefox Windows but not on Android

Tags: javascript, android, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am using browser.runtime.setUninstallURL within my Firefox extension. However, I found the problem when this extension runs on Android. On Windows, Firefox opens a new tab with specified URL loaded for me. But, on Android, Firefox does not open a new tab when I uninstall my extension.

I have simplified my background.js code to the following -

```
function onSetURL() {
  console.log("set uninstall URL");
}

function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

function handleInstalled(details) {
        var settingUrl = browser.runtime.setUninstallURL('http://www.google.com');
        settingUrl.then(onSetURL, onError);
}

browser.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(handleInstalled);
```

Edit: add manifest.json

```
     {
      "name": "Firefox T",
      "description": "Firefox T.1.0",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "developer": {
      "name": "firefoxt@firefoxt.firefoxt"
      },

      "applications": {
      "gecko": {
        "id": "firefoxt@firefoxt.firefoxt",
        "strict_min_version": "58.0"
        }
      },

      "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Firefox T.1.0"
      },

      "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
      },

      "permissions":["<all_urls>","http://*/*","https://*/*","webNavigation","webRequest","webRequestBlocking","cookies","tabs","activeTab","storage","management"]
     }
```

Then signed it on AMO and tested it on both Windows and Android. On Windows, it works as expected. I found the problem only on Android.

I even try to use WebIDE to see if onSetURL() is run during the installation. I uninstall it in less than a minute later. I found the folllowing log in WebIDE and Browser Console.

[image: log from WebIDE]

[image: log from Browser Console]

Comment: Which Firefox for Android version did you use? It's implemented starting from version 48.

Comment: I use the latest which is 59.0.2.

Comment: Try filing a bug: http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ (product Toolkit)

Comment: Thanks. Done. [https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1461882](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1461882)

Comment: Not a single response. Must I put the priority into it? Can I email triage owner directly ?

Comment: I would suggest using a workaround until it is fixed. It's also helpful to be around when the bug becomes active. You can't e-mail the triage owner.

Comment: Got it. And there are some updates already. Thank you for your help.